# Can't edit file in root with root permissions

Tags: permissions, root

Ubuntu machine 18.04.
I have root privileges on the machine but when I try to edit a file using root, I am not able to.

The same file I can edit without root permissions.

How to change this so that I can edit files with root privileges?

Example:

1. suppose I open a file with root@server:-~$ vi file1
2. Edit the file and try to save it with "ESC :wq enter"
3. I recieve the error as "File is Read Only"

Comment: Provide detail (edit your question) on how you try to edit a file with root permission, and where it fails. "I am not able to" is not what I would call a very specific description of the problem.

Comment: It is under root itself.